# Migrating Django-machina models-django unable to locate app

Tags: python, django, database-design

I'm trying to make a forum to my django website using the machina framework. And I've modified the forum_member app as per the documentation (https://django-machina.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customization/recipes/overriding_models.html). And my dir structure is as follows: 
project has the main apps and manage.py.
Inside this project folder, there is another folder called apps which contains machina's overwritten apps.

```
folder\<project apps>
folder\manage.py
folder\forumapps.pth
folder\apps
folder\apps\__init__.py
folder\apps\forum_member
folder\apps\forum_member\__init__.py
folder\apps\forum_member\models.py
folder\apps\forum_member\migrations
folder\apps\forum_member\migrations\<migrations files copied from the original forum_member in machina installation in python>Lib>site-packages>
```

My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'payments',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'mptt',
    'haystack',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'pagedown',
    'forum_member',
) + tuple(get_machina_apps())
```

and I've added a forumapps.pth file at the Project level containing:

```
# machina package configuration
apps
```

Now, when I run `python manage.py makemigrations forum_member`, it shows the following error:

```
E:\btcat>python manage.py makemigrations forum_member
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in popu
late
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create

    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named forum_member
```

I'm scouring through the internet to find a solution but to no avail. Can anyone help me understand whats wrong and what I need to do to get my modified machina app & its models up and running?

All help greatly appreciated!! Thank you!!

Comment: Two things to try: replace `'forum_member',` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` with `'apps.forum_member',`. Or try to move your forum_member code into your project directory rather than nesting it in `apps/`. It is possible a directory structure like this is fine, but I have never tried it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `.pth` file is ignored unless you put it in the `site-packages` folder. An alternative is to add the "apps" folder to the env variable `PYTHONPATH` instead.